# Python: socket issue with str command

Tags: python, string, sockets, server, client

i have an issue in send str command from server to client.
i wanna sent str value (for ex: "Hello, You Are Connected to the server").
but in client program show (b'Hello, You Are Connected to the server)
how i can clear the "b'....'"?
Server:

```
#The Server Socket Program
import socket
s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("localhost",5225))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    print("Recinving a Connection from: ",addr)
    conn.send(str.encode('Hello, You Are Connected to the server'))
    conn.close()
```

Client:

```
#The Client Program
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost",5225))
s.send(str.encode("Hello Server"))
data=s.recv(2048)
print(data) 
s.close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIkTf.jpg)

Comment: `print(data.decode('utf-8'))` If you encode, you must decode.

Comment: That's just notation that it is a byte string.  You can just `s.send(b'hello')` or `s.send('hello'.encode())`.  You can't send Unicode strings directly...they must be encoded to send and decoded after receive.